# How can I convert an html response by an api request to a normal text inside a RichTextBox in C# Windows forms Application

Tags: c#, html, .net, winforms, richtextbox

Please Help! I am trying to develop a sticky-notes application that has the capability of Bionic-Reading. I have used an api from rapidapi to implement it. The problem I'm encountering is that I can't convert the html response by the api to a normal text and set it inside a rich text box.

Here's my code:

```
var client = new RestClient(@"This is My Endpoint Client");
var request = new RestRequest("This is My Endpoint Request", @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddHeader("X-RapidAPI-Key", "This is My Key");
request.AddHeader("X-RapidAPI-Host", "This is My Host");

string content = string.Format("content={0}.&response_type=html&request_type=html&fixation=1&saccade=10", txtnote.Text);
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", content, ParameterType.RequestBody);
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

try
{
    if (response.IsSuccessful)
    {
        txtnote.Text = response.Content;
        txtnote.Rtf = ConvertHtmlToRtf(txtnote);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(response.StatusCode.ToString());
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

public static string ConvertHtmlToRtf(RichTextBox richTextBox)
{
    string tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();

    try
    {
        richTextBox.SaveFile(tempFileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(tempFileName))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        File.Delete(tempFileName);
    }
}
```

I want this response from the api be converted into a normal text and display it in the richtextbox
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF8Xr.png)

Appreciate All your Responses!! Thank you!

I tried searching different methods from the net, but I just can't implement the right method for my desired output. I have installed the library using TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.Core; using TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.WinForms;, but I can't find the detailed documentation of it that's why I'm lost in using it.

Comment: I bet putting html into a RichTextBox and saving it will not give you the desired results. Perhaps there is a 3rd party Html2Rtf that can be more useful in this situation.

Comment: Are you sure you cannot ask a `response_type` other than HTML? This might be useful if you post this request from a Web app. For a Desktop App, you could use WebView2 to host a HTML page, or request a different format (since it appears there's a choice there, maybe JSON?) and handle it in some other way

Comment: Hi thanks for your responses, here's what I found from the documentation of the api. 
"You can choose between "html" and "page". "html" returns HTML code to embed, while "page" returns HTML code ready to embed in your application or webpage as iframe."

Comment: Sorry but, I'm really new when it comes to using api on desktop applications, could anyone help me what and how can I use a page 'response_type' and display the appropriate results?